# Check if app opened by DeepLink or not

Tags: ionic-framework, deep-linking

I have been usign the ionic deep links functionality using ionic deep links how do i find if the app is opened from a DeepLink or manually by the user ?
This is without considering the subscribe event .

I want to be able to provide to different functionality for users manually opening the app and second for people opening from deep links

Answer (score 0):

You can add params in the schema just as you add in a GET request.

```
intent://billdetails/' + PARAM_1 + '/' + PARAM_2 + '/' + PARAM_3 + '/#Intent;scheme=lvhlthAndroid;S.browser_fallback_url=' +some_fallback_url+ ';end
```

This is an example launch schema URL for Android App, Your app will be looking for the schema `lvhlthAndroid` here.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [Deep Link Tester app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manoj.dlt&hl=en)  in Android OS to check if app opened by DeepLink or not. Hope this will help to you.